# Projecting onto Matrix-Valued Linear Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

I want to break up my problem into two parts:

**1. Projecting onto a Particular Subspace**

Let $P \in GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ be arbitrary, and consider the collection

$$
Sym_P(\mathbb{R}) \;\; =\;\; \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; A^T = P^{-1}AP \}.
$$

We can verify fairly easily that this is a vector subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$, which means we can do all kinds of linear algebra on $Sym_P(\mathbb{R})$.  My question is how to explicitly uncover the orthogonal projection $\pi_P: M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to Sym_P(\mathbb{R})$ taking any arbitrary matrix $A \to \tilde{A}$ such that $\tilde{A}^T = P^{-1}\tilde{A}P$.

**2. Projecting onto an Intersection of Subspaces**

Suppose now I have some other vector subspace of $M_n(\mathbb{R})$.  For instance we can consider the spaces

\begin{eqnarray*}
H_n(\mathbb{R}) & = & \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; A_{ii} = 0, \; \forall i = 1,\ldots, n\} \\
\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R}) & = & \{A \in M_n(\mathbb{R}) \; | \; Tr(A) = 0\}.
\end{eqnarray*}

I would like to be able to uncover the orthogonal projections $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to Sym_P(\mathbb{R}) \cap H_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $M_n(\mathbb{R}) \to Sym_P(\mathbb{R}) \cap \mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{R})$.

**3. The General Approach**

This may be covered by elementary linear algebra texts, but I would like to know in general how to project vectors onto intersections of linear subspaces.  For instance, if we have a vector space $V$ and subspaces $U,W \subseteq V$, then what is an approach for uncovering the orthogonal projection $V \to U \cap W$?

Comment: If you want an orthogonal projection, you better start off with an inner product on your space first. Do you have an inner product on $M_n( \mathbb{R})$?

Comment: @OsamaGhani Yes, good point.  I was assuming the Euclidean inner product: $\langle A,B\rangle = Tr\left (A^TB\right )$.

Comment: I would suggest then finding a basis for $Sym_P (\mathbb{R})$, Gram-Schmidting it and then the map $\pi_P$ would be given by $ \sum_i <A,V_i> V_i$ where $V_i$ is a vector in the orthonormal basis.